# Is there a more efficient way to do things according to which checkboxes are checked?

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, checkbox, .net-4.0

I just recently encountered this issue myself, and searching for this issue has turned up no fruits yet...

So let's say I have four checkboxes, as an example, and I want to do certain things based on which of them are checked at any time...

```
if (CB1.Checked)
{
    //Do things here if only checkbox 1 is checked.
}
else if (CB2.Checked)
{
    //Do things here if only checkbox 2 is checked.
}
else if (CB3.Checked)
{
    //Do things here if only checkbox 3 is checked.
}
else //if (CB4.Checked)
{
    //Do things here if only checkbox 4 is checked.
}
```

I'm sure most people will tend to use something like the example code snippet above, or a variation of it. It looks simple, right? But what if... you aren't just checking for only one checkbox alone?

```
if (CB1.Checked && CB2.Checked)
{
    //Do things here if only checkbox 1 & 2 is checked.
}
else if (CB2.Checked && CB3.Checked)
{
    //Do things here if only checkbox 2 & 3 is checked.
}
else if (CB3.Checked && CB1.Checked)
{
    //Do things here if only checkbox 3 & 1 is checked.
}
else if (CB4.Checked && CB1.Checked)
{
    //Do things here if only checkbox 4 & 1 is checked.
}
else if (CB4.Checked && CB2.Checked)
{
    //Do things here if only checkbox 4 & 2 is checked.
}
else //if (CB4.Checked && CB3.Checked)
{
    //Do things here if only checkbox 4 & 3 is checked.
}
```

As can be seen... the number of if-else statements have increased... And it will, if you wanted to compare perhaps even more checkboxes than 4, or for more checkboxes out of 4... And that could complicate things, with (likely) most programmers being unable to avoid it.

I should also mention that I know how many checkboxes are checked at a given time, thanks to this code:

```
private int GetNumberOfCheckboxesChecked()
{
    int NumberofCheckBoxesChecked = 0;
    foreach (Control c in groupBox1.Controls)
    {
        if ((c is CheckBox) && ((CheckBox)c).Checked)
            NumberofCheckBoxesChecked++;
    }

    return NumberofCheckBoxesChecked;
}
```

They will also need to check one of the checkboxes at all times, as each checkbox's checkchanged event calls this code:

```
private void OneAtLeast(object originalSender)
{
    CheckBox tempCB = (CheckBox)originalSender;
    if (!CB1.Checked && !CB2.Checked && !CB3.Checked && !CB4.Checked)
    {
        tempCB.Checked = true;
        MessageBox.Show("You must select at least one option!", "Invalid Operation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

So, **my question is...** is there a better (or more efficient, or can reduce the lines of code) way to do things according to which checkbox/checkboxes is/are checked? Or are we really stuck to this method (or variations of this method)?

**Do note that for this example, whatever you would be doing according to which checkboxes are checked... can't simply be "added on" or "appended".**

It should also be noted that the switch-case method will be more or less the same as this method... so it would most likely not make a difference. It has also been [concluded elsewhere that if-statements are more efficient that switch-case.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44959/how-can-i-make-three-if-else-statements-more-efficient)

Comment: This is a good question, but do you have a more specific use-case? How do the values of the checkboxes interact? I find it hard to believe you have 16 completely different options based on the values of 4 checkboxes.

Comment: Just a small note: the code you provided will not work. You would need to have something like this for each condition: `(CB1.Checked && CB2.Checked && !CB3.Checked && !CB4.Checked)` else you will get false results.

Comment: The values of the checkboxes don't really interact that much, I would say. But it would do something quite different to each of the other combinations. There are no mathematics involved with this scenario though.

Comment: @Ulric true, I missed that out, while writing the question, sorry! Edit: Added a most likely relevant piece of code that might help fix that.

Comment: @Kaitlyn No need for an apology. If we were perfect then we'd probably be better paid. ;)

Comment: You could generate some unique string or whatever on the `CheckedChange`event of each checkbox, writing that string to a hidden text field or label. That way you wouldn't have to check for each checkbox but simply read the result of your hidden label text and use that as condition.

Comment: @LocEngineer That will only result in the if-else statements being the same number as before? You're only replacing the CheckBox.Checked statements with that.

Comment: @Kaitlyn well is was worth a brain fart. Also if some combination of checkboxes excludes others that should be caught beforehand anyway and then the number of ifs or cases can surely be reduced. All depends on what exactly the OP tries to achieve anyway. Looks a bit flawed to me to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there's much you can do about the number of branches. If the logic permits, you can deal with some of it by nesting `if` statements. But this only is useful in certain cases, and it makes matters worse in others.

If you truly have 16 different, unrelated options for 4 checkboxes you're better off using a `switch`, or a lookup dictionary as @Damien_The_Unbeliever suggests. The one thing that you lose with the `switch` or lookup is readability because you basically end up translating checkbox values into a bitmask and performing actions based on a final "magic" integer value. Of course if the checkboxes are actually *numbered* as you have them, it's probably easy enough to keep track of which one is which bit. But if the names are something like `ApplesCheckBox`, `SeedsCheckBox`, `SoilCheckBox`, you'll have a hard time matching this to an integer bitmask.

You can get some of this back with a flags enumeration. For example, piggybacking off of [@Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32436844/44853):

```
[Flags]
enum CheckboxActions
{
    None = 0,

    CheckBox1 = 1,
    CheckBox2 = 2,
    CheckBox3 = 4,
    CheckBox4 = 8,

    DoJustCB1 = 1,
    DoJustCB2 = 2,
    DoCB1AndCB2ButNeverCB4 = 3
}
```

Then,

```
var option = CheckboxActions.None;

if(CB1.Checked) option = option | CheckboxActions.CheckBox1;
if(CB2.Checked) option = option | CheckboxActions.CheckBox2;
if(CB3.Checked) option = option | CheckboxActions.CheckBox3;
if(CB4.Checked) option = option | CheckboxActions.CheckBox4;
```

To use it, for example in a switch:

```
switch (option)
{
    case CheckboxActions.None:
        DoNothingNoOptionsSet();
        break;
    case CheckBoxActions.DoJustCB1:
        DoJustCB1();
        break;
    case CheckBoxActions.DoJustCB2:
        DoJustCB2();
        break;
    case CheckBoxActions.DoCB1AndCB2ButNeverCB4:
        DoCB1AndCB2ButNeverCB4();
        break;
}
```

Or just set up a `Dictionary<CheckboxActions, Action>` and use it as a lookup.

You can use appropriate names for the enum values, so you know exactly what's going on, and the order of checkboxes is encapsulated by the enum values `CheckboxActions.CheckBox1` through `CheckboxActions.CheckBox4`. As a bonus, you get a bit more type safety passing around a `CheckboxActions` to different classes and methods than you do with a plain old `int`.

---

In fact, in playing with this, I just learned you can reference enum values from within the same enum. So you can *completely* remove magic values and the above becomes (and yes, this compiles):

```
[Flags]
enum CheckboxActions
{
    None = 0,

    CheckBox1 = 1,
    CheckBox2 = 2,
    CheckBox3 = 4,
    CheckBox4 = 8,

    DoJustCB1 = CheckboxActions.CheckBox1,
    DoJustCB2 = CheckboxActions.CheckBox2,
    DoCB1AndCB2ButNeverCB4 = CheckboxActions.CheckBox1 | CheckboxActions.CheckBox2
}
```

Comment: Don't you love it when you learn something new while answering a SO question?

Comment: Turns out this (improvement onto Damien's) answer is the one that really works for me ;p   Mainly due to the methods that will be called using lists within a list(s) that are currently uninitialized but will be, while the program is running. Either that, or I still have things I don't understand about dictionary (or actions and delegates in regard to methods).

Comment: Oh, just learnt that "Actions" can receive parameters, but not return values. Bummer. My methods do receive and return XD

Comment: @Kaitlyn So use a `Func`.

Comment: Ahh. Gotta love those bit flags.

Comment: Well, no go with a "Func" lol. Already tried, but it failed miserably on me. One of my func is actually 4 that accepts different number of parameters. Yours already helped me to achieve what I was trying to do, in a more effective way ;p

Comment: Sounds like you could probably solve this with another layer of abstraction then.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a dictionary mapping `int`s to `Action`s or `Func`s (or whatever else is appropriate) and then use the checkboxes to set bits in an integer. Once you've computed the integer, you look it up in the dictionary and dispatch to that method. The dictionary can be initialised once.

E.g.

```
int option = 0;
if(CB1.Checked) option = option | 1;
if(CB2.Checked) option = option | 2;
if(CB3.Checked) option = option | 4;
if(CB4.Checked) option = option | 8;

if(!lookup.HasKey(option))
    throw new NotSupportedException("I didn't expect that combination of options");

lookup[option]();
```

Where `lookup` has previously been initialised (possibly it's a `static` member of the class)

```
lookup = new Dictionary<int,Action>();
lookup.Add(0,DoNothingNoOptionsSet);
lookup.Add(1,DoJustCB1);
lookup.Add(2,DoJustCB2);
lookup.Add(3,DoCB1AndCB2ButNeverCB4);
/* etc, for other valid options */
```

This also gives you the opportunity to apply descriptive names to each function that is performed, to move them out into separate functions, and to then combine the areas where there *is* common functionality into smaller helper functions.

Comment: Isn't this just effectively abstracting out a switch statement and moving it into initialization code somewhere unrelated to the current method instead? Unless you plan on performing the same action from multiple places, what would be the benefit of this over just `switch(option)`?

Comment: @lc - with the number of combinations currently contemplated (16) and possibly more in the future, I'd be wanting to move the code out into separate methods anyway. So I'm also shortcutting creating a `switch` that then just invokes one function in each branch.

Comment: All combinations are to be expected, and allowed for though they would all result in different actions. They would also not be allowed to leave any checkbox unchecked thanks to another small piece of code, that forces them to check at least one ;)

Comment: Definitely agreed with moving the code into separate methods. And the more I think about it, the lookup is maybe cleaner; it lets you even inject different parts of it from different places if need be.

Comment: Guess this is the most efficient way for now, it seems, and what @lc. said. In fact, that's exactly what I was doing lol, each of the different combinations will call different functions that actually does the work. Just that to call the functions, the code had to know the exact combination of checkboxes before moving on.